# LINQ Expression in C#/Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

Im new to C#, Entity Framework and Linq hope there is someone who can explain something in the code about LINQ. I have a method inside my program that select a user from the table. That method is:

```
 public static cp_user SelectUser(string user, string passw)
    {
        try
        {
            cp_user entityUser = (from u in _db.cp_user
                                  where u.username == user && u.password == passw
                                  select u).FirstOrDefault();

            return entityUser;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

cp_user is the class corresponding to the table I have in my database. And _db is a field which holds a reference to the database instance.

In the select user method I understand that there is a creation of local variable of type cp_user and it is defined by the statement:

```
(from u in _db.cp_user
                              where u.username == user && u.password == passw
                              select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

1. Im confused about the first part of the statement. "From u in _dp.cp_user". 
   Ive been working with MySQL so far, so its confusing to see this "from u". In MySQL this "u" would be referring to a table. But in Linq im confused to what it does.
2. I do understand roughly the rest of the statement though, that the username and password arguments in the method must be equal to data that is in the table. And that it will return the database object. But again confused about the u, in the last part saying select u.

Another question I have is in another method called checkany, which check if the user log in is correct:

```
 public static bool CheckAny(string user, string passw)
    {
        bool itIsAlredy = _db.cp_user.Any(u => u.username == user && u.password == passw);
        return itIsAlredy;
    }
```

I understand that it takes in username and password and creates a boolean variable which can either return true or false depending on the statement. Here is the part I dont understand.

3. For me this statement "(u => u.username == user && u.password == passw);" looks like it means that the username and password in the method parameters must be existent in the database. But someone at school told me that it means that both username and password must be corresponding correctly meaning; you can't have a password thats connected to another username. So what does this statement actually say. And also again I don't understand the whole "u => u.username". Like what does this u represent. Is it special linq syntax if so what does it mean?

Im very sorry if I have made any wrongly statements please correct me if I have im new to programming in general only worked with MySQL before. If anyone could answer the 3 questions I have would be greatly appreciated, and please have patience for my lack of knowledge.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `from u in _db.cp_user where u.username == user && u.password == passw Select u` is similar to `Select * from _db.cp_user WHERE username == user && password == passw`. The `from u in _db.cp_user` defines `u` as a row in the _db.cp_user table. Then it compares the username and password properties of the row, and if they meet the criteria, the row is selected (so these columns need to exist in the table). This is done for all rows, and they are returned as an IEnumerable, then `FirstOrDefault` returns either the first row or null.

Comment: Expressions with `=>` syntax are lambda expressions, like inline functions. You can read about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. from u in _db.cp_user is simple.  Just like a foreach loop you are defining an item in a collection. u is the item and _db.cp_user is the collection, its just looping through the collection and u is the handle of given item.
2. select u is just returning that particular item in the collection.
3. u => u.username is just checking to see if the u object (im guessing user) which has a property of username is the equal to that of the user string argument that is passed into the method

Answer (score 0):

The elements of the larger list are being passed element-wise to the methods. The lambda expression is written to take the elements using the input parameter `u`. This means that the person at school is correct, a single `u` must have both a `username == user` as well as `password == passw`.

For the `from` clause you can look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/from-clause